# Does Amazon SQS Receive Message Process Make it Unavailable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, message-bus

I'm new to SQS but I have worked with Azure Service Bus, and if I remember correctly, once you 'pop' a message from the queue it essentially no longer exists in the queue so you don't have to worry about multiple consumers getting the same message (please excuse me if this is incorrect).

I'm following the Amazon .NET SDK example for 'Receiving and Deleting' a message from the queue, which to me implies that until it is deleted it may be possible for another consumer to pick it up. Is this correct? Is there a way to remove it from the queue at the same time it is received or otherwise protect it from duplicate consuming?

```
// Receive a single message from the queue.
var receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest
{
    AttributeNames = { "GlobalTransactionId", "Amount", "TransactionDate" },
    MaxNumberOfMessages = 1,
    MessageAttributeNames = { "All" },
    QueueUrl = queueUrl,
    VisibilityTimeout = 0,
    WaitTimeSeconds = 0,
};

var receiveMessageResponse = await client.ReceiveMessageAsync(receiveMessageRequest);

// Delete the received message from the queue.
var deleteMessageRequest = new DeleteMessageRequest
{
    QueueUrl = queueUrl,
    ReceiptHandle = receiveMessageResponse.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle,
};

var deleteMessageResponse = await client.DeleteMessageAsync(deleteMessageRequest);
```

Comment: You need to manually delete it after consuming. It won’t appear to other consumers as long as you delete it within the visibility timeout. (or in rare cases if there is some issue with aws itself. Single processing can’t be guaranteed in non fifo queues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Amazon SQS message lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-architecture.html#sqs-message-lifecycle):

- A consumer calls `ReceiveMessage()` to request a message (or batch of messages) from the queue
- These messages will be marked as 'invisible' for a defined period of time
- Once the consumer has processed the message, it calls `DeleteMessage()` to remove the message from the queue
- If the consumer does *not* delete the message before the visibility timeout expires, then the message 'reappears' on the queue on the assumption that the consumer has failed

Your consumer could call `ReceiveMessage()` and then immediately call `DeleteMessage()` for each of the messages it received. However, this has the risk that the messages were not correctly consumed. It is your choice.

It is not possible to "remove it from the queue at the same time it is received".

To "protect it from duplicate consuming", ensure that the visibility timeout is several times greater than the time it takes to process the message. That is, the time between Receiving the message and Deleting it.